# How can I force boost::unit_test to pause after test is completed?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-unit-test-framework

When running console programs from Visual Studio, the console shows, program runs and then console disappears without giving you a chance to see it.

In general, I add those lines before `main`'s return statement:

```
std::cout << "Press enter to exit " << std::endl;
std::string sGot;
getline(std::cin, sGot);
```

How can I do something similar when program is compiled with `boost::unit_test` framework? As the `main` is directly part of the `boost` library, I can't modify it (I'd like to avoid recompiling `boost` for that).

Comment: Unrelated, but you can simply use `std::cin.get();` instead of `getline`

Comment: How about `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`?

Comment: @karastojko: Who cares what the command is? The point is where to add it? As we can't modify main program and this has to be done afetr last test was executed...

Comment: Run with Ctrl+F5, not just F5 if you do not need debugger. Alternatively, start your program through command line, as you are supposed to.

Comment: You could add a test that is dedicated to this purpose and is always run last.

Comment: @piwi: That's a nice approach. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a test that is dedicated to this purpose and is always run last.

Edit (completed by jpo38):

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( PauseWhenDone )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( do_pause )
{
    std::cout << "Press enter to exit " << std::endl;
    std::string sGot;
    getline(std::cin, sGot);
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Visual Studio preference:

- go to Menu > Tools > Options, you see the option dialog like the image below
- navigate to "Debugging"
- Uncheck "Automatically close the console when debugging stops"

[image]

Comment: This is new in VS2017 and VS2019.